# Is this object will dispose automatically when encounter exception?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

```
using(YourType yourObject = new YourType())
{
   //Treatment on you object 
   //Exception occurs here
}
```

when we write this way, the garbage collector automatically disposes the object, but is exceptions occurs inside this will the garbage collector still dispose the object or I have to write something for it, I know this is a lame q but m really confused, thnx

please explain the treatment in different .net frameworks to make things crystal clear.

Comment: The garbage collector does *not* automatically dispose the object. The garbage collector has nothing to do with the `using` statement. A `using` statement is just syntactic sugar for a try/finally block with a Dispose call in the finally block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the using block will still call `Dispose` on an exception. See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.

Also another useful article [Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.

```
using (var object = new Object())
{
    object.DoSomething();
}
```

equal with:

```
var object = new Object();
try
{
     object.DoSomething();
}
finally
{
    object.Dispose();
}
```